# How to enable https support in twitteR?

Tags: twitter, https, rcurl

I am trying to connect to twitter using the twitteR package in R.  Script and results are below.  Running R 3.1.2 64 bit on windows 8.1.  Any suggestions about how to enable https?  I've not found a solution on R-help or any other searchable source.

```
require(twitteR)
Loading required package: twitteR
Loading required package: ROAuth
Loading required package: RCurl
Loading required package: bitops
Loading required package: rjson
> cred <- OAuthFactory $ new( consumerKey = my.key, consumerSecret = my.secret, requestURL =' https:// api.twitter.com/ oauth/ request_token', accessURL =' https:// api.twitter.com/ oauth/ access_token', authURL =' https:// api.twitter.com/ oauth/ authorize')
> cred$handshake(cainfo = "C:/users/john/documents/twitter/cacert.pem")
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  Protocol " https" not supported or disabled in libcurl
```

Answer (score 0):

URL's for requestURL and following were specified with a single quote.  When the single quotes were replaced with a double quote and spaces removed, the function worked on Windows.